# MySQL Local Database Replication

Tags: mysql, web-services, replication

Is it possible to replicate a database to a second database in the same server?
I want to replicate a database that is used for an application, and create a copy that will be used for webservice testing puposes, like creating fake orders, fake data, etc... and it would be very nice to get updates from the main db, like product data updates...

I think i could use the binlog-do-db (or something similar) in mysql config and use the server as master and slave, but i played with that config before and had problems. In my current replications i replicate the entire mysql server, so it works.

Also, i dont want to replicate table1 to table1 and instead, table1 to table2. I dont know if thats allowed.

Is this the best approach or i'm trying to do something wrong/not possible? What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You might be tempted to try to set up a single mysqld instance as master and slave with [replicate-same-server-id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-same-server-id); this won't work, as the [server-id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options.html#option_mysqld_server-id) must be unique between every other ID in use by any other replication master or slave.

See this [Percona article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/) on [binlog-do-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-db) et al. You could achieve this with running [another mysqld instance on the same node](http://www.howtoforge.com/one_machine_mysql_replication), and configure on the slave [replicate-rewrite-db](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-rewrite-db) to apply statements to a different database name. I do not see anything about rewriting table names in replication options, though.

Alternatively, depending on the size of the database you are looking to duplicate, you may [mysqldump and import to another database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8892).